# Any idea why this post request won't work?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, post

I am trying to send this information into a webhook, but the webhook isn't catching the second post method I am attempting. The first one works. Obviously, the "API QUERY" and the "ID" in the webhook contain custom variables. Can you tell me why it is? I know that the if statement itself works because it will log the information that I need.

```
function myFunction() {

  var data = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'age': 35,
  'pets': ['fido', 'fluffy']
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/Id/Id/', options);

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("API QUERY GOES HERE")
   
  
var content = res.getContentText();

var json = JSON.parse(content);

var gratuityAmount = 17

for (i=0; i<json.items.length; i++){
  
  var orderName = json["items"][i]["name"];
  var orderId = json["items"][i]["id"];


  // Write an if statment that says "if the variable orderName contains "ezCater Order", then continue, all else stop

  if (orderName.includes("ThisOrder")) {

    var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/Id/Id/', options)
  };

  };
}
```

Comment: In your script, what you want to do at `'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)`? Can you provide the sample request body you want to expect here?

Comment: `orderName: ORDERNAME
orderId: 13444444444
gratuityAmount: 17 `

I actually figured it out by creating an object like this 

  `payload = { orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount }`

but it actually only returns the last object in the for loop, not all of them.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to use `payload = { orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount }`, your script is required to modify from `'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)` to `'payload': JSON.stringify({orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount})`.  How about this?

Comment: It is only returning the last object of the payload I am trying to send. Do you know how to loop through and send all of the objects instead of just the last one?

Comment: If you are saying about `var orderName = json["items"][i]["name"];` and `var orderId = json["items"][i]["id"];`, unfortunately, I cannot see the value of `json`. So I cannot think of your current issue. For example, can you provide the sample values of `json`?

Comment: json is me parsing the values I pull from the query 
`var content = res.getContentText();` to `var json = JSON.parse(content);`

This is what I am grabbing the index of, but I am looping through it in the original loop above to grab all of them, now I need to loop through the ones I grab to push to the webhook. 
`{
"items": [
{
"id": 5788549471,
"name": "My job name"}] ` Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the value of `json` is `{ "items": [ { "id": 5788549471, "name": "My job name"},,,]}` you provided, your script can use each element in the array by modifying from `'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)` to `'payload': JSON.stringify({orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount})`. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. I apologize for this. Can you provide detailed information for correctly replicating your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, by including the explanation, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If you got useful information for you from it, I'm glad.

Answer (score 1):

From your provided information, I understood your situation as follows.

- Value of `json` is like `{ "items": [ { "id": 5788549471, "name": "My job name"},,,]}`.
- You want to use `var orderName = json["items"][i]["name"];`, `var orderId = json["items"][i]["id"];` and `var gratuityAmount = 17` as `payload = { orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount }` in the loop.

In this case, it is required to modify `'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)`.

Because the arguments of `JSON.stringify` is `JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)`. In your script of  `'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)`, the 1st argument is put as the value. By this, only the value `orderName` is returned. I think that this is the reason for your issue.

If you want to use `'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)` as `payload = { orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount }` in the loop, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
'payload': JSON.stringify(orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount)
```

#### To:

```
'payload': JSON.stringify({orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount})
```

- By this, `{orderName, orderId, gratuityAmount}` is used as `{orderName: orderName, orderId: orderId, gratuityAmount: gratuityAmount}`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

#### References:

- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)